# What is the maximum file size 32 bit java can access?

Tags: java, file, file-io

What is the maximum file size 32 bit java can access?

Is this architecture dependent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[2^63-1](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) bytes (because the Java API [uses 64bit integers for file sizes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length())) or platform dependent (if the platform has some limitations, for example FAT32).

Answer (score 2):

And it has nothing to do with '32-bit' Java. That describes the memory address space, not the file system.